# Reusable Priority queue implementation in google go

Tags: algorithm, go, priority-queue, reusability

How would one go about writing the code for a reusable priority queue in Google Go or is one expected to define the `Less` `Push` and `Pop` function everytime a priority queue implementation is needed?

Answer (score 3):

The later case is what one has to do. As far as Go doesn't have generics, it's the only available option at the moment.

Comment: I remember a certain amount of grouching when Go was launched, that the language bultins are generic but there's no way to write your own. C++ programmers expect the earth ;-)

Answer (score 1):

Haven't tried it, but maybe you could use reflection and struct tags, if your cases happened to fit certain restrictons.  You would require that your heapable type be a struct with a tag like `pq:"Key"` on the field you use for ordering, and that that field type be < comparable.  It's far less powerful than a Less method but it might meet your needs.

Sorry I have no example code for you.  I don't think it wouldn be terribly hard, but it would take me some time.  Left for an exercise.

I might try this technique if I had a situation where I needed to handle arbitrary structs and I could live with the simplistic key restriction.  For a finite set of types though, I wouldn't do this.  I would just do it by the book, implementing heap.Interface separately for each type.  It's really not that much work nor that many lines of code.

Answer (score 0):

There used to be vector types in the `container/vector` module of the standard library that implemented these methods, based on a resizable slice, and perfectly worked as the container to be used with the `heap` module. Unfortunately, they got rid of `vector`, which I never understood as it implemented a nice method-level abstraction over a slice variable. So now, every time I see someone using the heap module in Go, they have to basically re-implement part of `vector` -- writing `Push`, `Pop`, `Length`, etc. based on a slice variable.

Comment: Then `container.Vector` got obsoleted also b/c of [SliceTricks](http://code.google.com/p/go-wiki/wiki/SliceTricks). The other reason was that `Vector` supported only 3 types (`int`, `string`, `interface{}`) but the referenced tricks are usable any statically type safe for any type-

Comment: @jnml: You didn't read what I said. The `heap` algorithms requires a type with the methods `Push`, `Pop`, `Len`, `Less`, and `Swap`. `Vector` has all of those already. SliceTricks doesn't help.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure I understand the question.

I've implemented a queue (and stack and ring) using interface{} as the stored type here:

https://github.com/iNamik/go_container

Using interface{} allows you to store any type you want - although it doesn't help you enforce types ala generics, it gets the job done.

I could see creating a priority queue without much hassle.

Am I missing something?

I'd be happy to add a priority queue container if you think you'd find it useful.